# Violations in cryptocurrency services

Tags: google-developers-console

It appears that this project has violations of the Terms of Service for the free trial period regarding cryptocurrency mining

Hi, I'm receiving this warning on my panel, but I can't resolve it, and I'm afraid of stopping my servers, does anyone know how to resolve this warning, I've never worked with cryptocurrencies, I work with VoIP telephony, my account is on my CNPJ

I have already filled out the form, but every time Google responds it says that my argument was not accepted